# Difficulties with dispalying progressdialog

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I need to display progrees dialog. It is quite simple, however I am absolutly required to wait untill asynctask will finish. That exopse some difficulties to me. To wait for completion of asynctask method `.get()` is used. But this method `blocks` my progress dialog. 
So, how can I unblock `progressdialog` with get or what can replace `.get()`?

I am calling operation in a following way:

```
Operation o = new Operation();
o.execute(params);
try {
            o.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

class Operation

```
class Operation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {
        ProgressDialog pd;
        Context con;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            pd = new ProgressDialog(app);
            pd.setOwnerActivity(app);
            pd.setTitle("Идет загрузка...");
            pd.setCancelable(true);
            pd.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... option) {
            /*
            some job
            */

            return json;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            pd.dismiss();

            /* 
            some job
            */
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is the problem in showing in onPreExecute and hiding in onPostExecute?

Comment: forgot to remove comments. The problem with preexecute/postexecute - dialog does not pop-up when .get() is called. In that case dialog flashes for half second when asynctask is done.

Comment: you cand call the get method in doInBackground

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `.get()` as you have seen it blocks the `UI`. You can use `getStatus()` if you need to check if the task is finished. Removing `.get()` should allow your `ProgressDialog` to show. If you have code that must wait until the `AsyncTask` is finished then put it in `onPostExecute()` or call a function from there

If you need to reference something in the `MainActivity` from the `AsyncTask` after it has finished, simply create a constructor to take a reference of your `Activity` and pass `context` to your `constructor`

```
Operation o = new Operation(this);
```

and reference it in constructor

```
lass Operation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {
    ProgressDialog pd;
    Context con;
    Activity act;

  public Operator(Activity curAct)
  {
      act = curAct;   // can use this reference to access methods in your Activity  
   }
```

Comment: That sounds good. However can I  put another asynctaks on postExecute() of the first asynctask? The nesessity of .get() arrised, because i gave  several network operation, where fisrt network call downloads options for next operation.

Answer (score 1):

try to use this way

```
private ProgressDialog dialog=null;

     @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Please! Wait...",true);
            }


            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                dialog.dismiss();
               // use here code
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to change your code to something like this.
Wrap the code you want to run afterwards in a runnable and pass it to your async task.

```
 Runnable onEnd = new Runnable(){
    //code to run after the task has completed
 }
 Operation o = new Operation(onEnd);
 o.execute(params);
```

And here is the modified Operation class.

```
class Operation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {
    ProgressDialog pd;
    Context con;
    Runnable afterwards = null;

    Operation(Runnable afterwards){
      this.afterwards  = afterwards ;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pd = new ProgressDialog(app);
        pd.setOwnerActivity(app);
        pd.setTitle("Идет загрузка...");
        pd.setCancelable(true);
        pd.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... option) {
        /*
        some job
        */

        return json;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        pd.dismiss();

        /* 
        some job
        */
        if (afterwards  != null)
           afterwards.run();
    }
}
```

Note the `afterwards.run()` in `onPostExecute`.